# Can't get StdIn library to work

Tags: stdin

I'm trying to learn java so I have little or no idea what I'm doing.
I have to use [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/StdIn.java) library but whenever I try to compile it/use in a program I get the error:

```
StdIn.java:223: error: cannot find symbol vals[i] = Double.parseDouble(fields[i]);
    symbol: method parseDouble(String)
    location: class Double
```

I tried the code [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/Average.java). (I assumed that since it's on the books website it'll work)

Can anyone tell me in DumbPeopleLanguage what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Third line: "Dependencies: StdIn.java StdOut.java". You need to put those two files in the same directory.

Comment: Both of them are in the same directory

Comment: Oh right, could it be that you have to import java.lang.Double?

Comment: O sh...
Thank you so much
It works now
:)